# Sitecore eXperience Profiler Tool Profile Page doesn't show data from Sitecore WebApi Calls

Tags: experience-profile

In our implementation, when try to visit the Sitecore Experience Profile's individual profile pages, it doesn't show any event related data.

I can see its returning following errors on Web browser console.

Also, cannot see any errors on the sitecore logs.

[image]

[image]

[image]

When try to open the webApi call urls in a separate tab, it doesn't return anything. "Page cannot be reached"

Any help on what could be the issue ?

Version : Sitecore 8.2

Comment: Try opening some of the faliling API endpoints to see what error message is returned: journey?serverSorting...., latest-statistics?&pageSize=1....

Comment: @grg I have tried that.. it doesn't return anything.. "page cannot be reached". Updated the question with that info.

Comment: Can you see any messages in Sitecore logs? Are Contacts and Interactions collections in MongoDB accessible?

Comment: @grg There are no information/error on logs for these requests. MongoDB is accessible and doesn't have any authentication defined.